# Why does my Roblox for loop not work? Doesn't print all outputs

Tags: for-loop, lua, roblox

So I am making a CameraScript on roblox studio that when the player touches a robot, the camera focuses on the robot. But the for loop seems to not work though.

The script in game.StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts:

```
workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable

game.Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    local g = char.Name
    print(g) --Just for debugging purposes
    print("Player Loaded!")
    
    tou(char)
end)

function tou(char)
    print("Function had ran")
    for _,p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
        print("We're here loopin ur parts...")
        p.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
            print("Someone touched?")
            if hit.Parent.Name == "Robot" and hit.Parent:IsA("Model") then
                print("It's the robot!")
                workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame = hit.Parent.Look.CFrame
                workspace.CurrentCamera.Focus = hit.Parent.Head.CFrame
                print("Camlock should be successfull...")
            else
                print("That ain't a robot tho...")
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

This is the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
for _,p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
    print("We're here loopin ur parts...")
    p.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        print("Someone touched?")
        if hit.Parent.Name == "Robot" and hit.Parent:IsA("Model") then
            print("It's the robot!")
            workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame = hit.Parent.Look.CFrame
            workspace.CurrentCamera.Focus = hit.Parent.Head.CFrame
            print("Camlock should be successfull...")
        else
            print("That ain't a robot tho...")
        end
    end)
end
```

I tried putting the for loop inside directly the CharacterAdded event, putting print() for debugging but it only printed these:

```
17:55:24.242  <username>  -  Client - CamLockOnKill:5
17:55:24.243  Player Loaded!  -  Client - CamLockOnKill:6
17:55:24.243  Function had ran  -  Client - CamLockOnKill:12
```

...but it didn't print the others.

Comment: I'm not familiar with developing for Roblox so I don't know what `GetChildren()` exactly does but the only explanation is that it seems the char doesn't have any children

Comment: The CharacterAdded detects if the player have loaded in the world and the char parameter in the function() at line 3 gets the player model and the event only runs if the character is loaded (hence the name), so there is no way my character has no children. But I'll still try.

Comment: I don't know much about Roblox, but what are children? And why do you think the char has at least one? Your result really should just mean that it doesn't have any children

Comment: That's very odd, by the time CharacterAdded is called, you _should_ have a character model in the Workspace. Maybe it's a timing issue, try putting a`wait()` in the function before `tou` gets called? Maybe try a different signal like Player.CharacterAppearanceLoaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't print `We're here loopin ur parts...` so the loop isn't run.

The only way to not run a generic for loop like

```
for _,p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
end
```

without errors is to provide an empty table to `pairs`.

So `char` does not have any children. Find out why you think it has children and why it does not.

Comment: so if that table is empty and for loops don't produce errors with non empty tables then the CharacterLoaded event is the problem?

Comment: I don't see you handle a CharacterLoaded event here. You only handle CharacterAdded. Where did you give that player's model any children?

Comment: oh sorry I always misplace CharacterAdded to CharacterLoaded, anyways the children is got from the parameter in the CharacterAdded event
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded

Comment: In my local testing, it appears that the while Model exists, it is empty for a brief time. A simple work around is to add a `wait()` before iterating over the contents. The [docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded) say this is lacking thread safety, so it's possible that it's a simple race condition that can be avoided by yielding briefly.

Comment: It works now. So adding `wait()` makes the function wait for all my parts to load then the for loop runs.